# Create PDF from address in Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel, command-prompt, pdf-conversion

I have been hunting for hours and not come across a solution yet. I have a list of 2,000+ PDF files which hyperlink to an internal Sharepoint drive. My aim is to create a local copy of the PDFs either using VBA or Command Prompt, but so far I have not come across a sequence that has proved fruitful.

Is it possible to render PDFs simply from a list of http addresses?
Can this be accomplished using VBA?
If so, how?

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Check [this answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+vba+download+file). When you succeed with single file downloading, just wrap the code into a loop to download all of them.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need to do.  Are you trying to automate downloading a bunch of PDF's ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a list of 2000+ links in Column A of Sheet1. The code below will also mark whether a PDF file exists or not (URL validation) and record it in adjacent column B.

Also, if the internal website (sharepoint) requires forced login/password then this code might need modifications.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Download_PDF()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim FileData() As Byte
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wHttp As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim strDownloadDirectory As String
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wHttp = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set wHttp = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    'Provide destination directory
    strDownloadDirectory = "C:\MyDownloads"
    'Provide source range of list of hyperlinks
    Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    'If Download Directory (Destination) doesn't exist then create it.
    If Dir(strDownloadDirectory, vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir strDownloadDirectory

    'If there is no url then no point in continuing
    If rngSource.Cells.Count <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each rng In rngSource.Cells
        MyFile = rng.Text
        If CheckURL(MyFile) Then
            FileNum = FreeFile
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Downloading ..."
            TempFile = Right(MyFile, InStr(1, StrReverse(MyFile), "/") - 1)
            wHttp.Open "GET", MyFile, False
            wHttp.Send
            FileData = wHttp.ResponseBody
            FileNum = FreeFile
            Open "C:\MyDownloads\" & TempFile For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
                Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
            Close #FileNum
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Error while Downloading : " & Err.Description
                Err.Clear
            Else
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Download Successful!"
            End If
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "File not found !!"
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next
    Set wHttp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Open the folder [ " & strDownloadDirectory & " ] for the downloaded files..."
End Sub
```

---

```
'Validate the given URL (Hyperlinks)
Function CheckURL(URL) As Boolean
    Dim wHttp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wHttp = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set wHttp = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    wHttp.Open "HEAD", URL, False
    wHttp.Send
    If wHttp.Status = 200 Then
        CheckURL = True
    Else
        CheckURL = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have tried this script several times and am routinely met with File Not Found errors. Suspecting this might have to do with spaces in the URL, I subbed "%20" for the spaces and still received errors. I have removed the "http://" prefix and still am not having any success with this script...Ideas?

Comment: As I mentioned already - "if the internal website (sharepoint) requires forced login/password then this code might need modifications."

Comment: To check this - Try opening the PDF link in incognito mode and if that gives the login screen then the code needs modification.

Comment: I've tried opening the PDFs with and without validating the login screen, and using incognito mode and not.